# My QT Property does not update when animated

Tags: c++, qt, animation, properties

I want to animate a simple integer in QT. To do it, I created an int property and I animated it. I connected the finished() signal to a slot so I can see my new value when it's updated. If a read my property, it always shows 1, but if I read the integer attached to the property, it udpates. Why don't I see my property updates ?

Here is my code:

**.h**

```
class MaFenetre : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    MaFenetre();
    int getToBeAnimated();
    void setToBeAnimated(int);

private slots:
    void valueChanged(QVariant);


private:
    int _toBeAnimated;
    Q_PROPERTY(int toBeAnimated READ getToBeAnimated WRITE setToBeAnimated)

};

#endif // MAFENETRE_H
```

**.cpp**

```
MaFenetre::MaFenetre() : QWidget()
{
    QPropertyAnimation *animation = new QPropertyAnimation(this, "toBeAnimated");
    animation->setDuration(10000);
    animation->setStartValue(0);
    animation->setEndValue(100);

    animation->start();
    connect(animation, SIGNAL(valueChanged(QVariant)), this, SLOT(valueChanged(QVariant)));

}

void MaFenetre::valueChanged(QVariant state){

    /////////////////////////////
    //////THIS DOESN'T WORK////// <-- WHY DOESN'T IT WORK ?
    /////////////////////////////
    int newValue = property("toBeAnimated").convert(QVariant::Int);

    /////////////////////////////
    //////THIS WORKS//////
    /////////////////////////////
    //int newValue = _toBeAnimated;

    //Shows the value of newValue
    qDebug(QString::number(newValue).toStdString().c_str());
}

int MaFenetre::getToBeAnimated(){
    return _toBeAnimated;
}

void MaFenetre::setToBeAnimated(int value){
    _toBeAnimated = value;
}
```

Comment: Any reason why you declaring it with extra underscore? int _toBeAnimated;
Q_PROPERTY(int toBeAnimated READ getToBeAnimated WRITE setToBeAnimated)

Comment: @evilruff: I guess that is just personal styling question. People do things differently. :)

Comment: bobby4078, have you tried adding a signal and emit that in your setter after setting while also adding the `NOTIFY` marker to the Q_PROPERTY declaration as follows? `Q_PROPERTY(int toBeAnimated READ getToBeAnimated WRITE setToBeAnimated NOTIFY toBeAnimatedChanged)` and `_toBeAnimated = value; emit toBeAnimatedChanged` in the setter and `public signals: void toBeAnimatedChanged();` in the header? Please let me know if that makes it work so that I can submit it as a proper answer.

Comment: Point is that this declaration  ( int toBeAnimated ) should match Q_PROPERTY declaration..